# Identify bad table or view references in stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014

I am looking for a way to identify stored procedures that refer to tables or views that are no longer available (i.e. that have been deleted), in order to help resolve these conflicts by editing the procedures. I would also like to be able to find and display the table or view names that do not exist. I am using SQL Server 2014.

Comment: What database are you working on?

Comment: My own database STG

Comment: On all three version of SQL or a specific one? You tagged all of them.

Comment: I am working on sql server 2014

Comment: Removed tags that are not applicable. Edited and improved grammar and question format.
This question still needs some example code or more explanation of what the author has tried. Ultimately this remains a poor quality question that does not demonstrate a significant amount of research on the part of the author.

Comment: I don't understand the vote down.  I voted it back up.  This is an excellent question.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query to list missing dependencies:

```
select
    object_name(referencing_id) as 'object making reference',
    referenced_class_desc,
    referenced_schema_name,
    referenced_entity_name as 'object name referenced',
    (select object_id from sys.objects where name = [referenced_entity_name]) as 'Object Found?'
from sys.sql_expression_dependencies e
    left join sys.tables t
    on e.referenced_entity_name = t.name
```

[Source](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/askjay/2012/07/22/finding-missing-dependencies/)

Comment: Can you please explain what to put in referenced entity name?

Comment: You have to use the query as it is.. It is using internal SQL tables